Kitchen under-sink RO tank will not fill following a toilet repair
AquaTru undersink RO system in kitchen, 6 months old, was working fine until I replaced a leaking water supply shutoff valve going to a bathroom toilet.
During toilet repair, I shut off main house water supply, opened a bathroom sink faucet and shower faucet, replaced the toilet supply shutoff valve, turned the main house water supply back on, shut off all faucets. Other than some air spurting in the line occasionally at the kitchen sink, there have been no other problems. Water pressure at all faucets appears normal. Yet, RO tank will no longer fill.
Any ideas on how to fix?
Thank you!

What happens when you run the water long enough at the kitchen sink and the RO faucet so that it no longer spurts air?

@DelphicOracle As of now, there's no air spurting at the kitchen faucet, and there's no water coming out of the RO faucet. When I open both at same time, there is normal flow of water from kitchen faucet and no water flow from RO faucet.

I am assuming that the line feeding the RO is the same line feeding the kitchen faucet. How old is the RO Membrane? The older the membrane, the longer the process to deliver water, which is not a lot in the first place. If you take the membrane out, do you get flow from the RO faucet?

@DelphicOracle You're onto something - I figured out the problem, and it relates to your hypothesis. I'm posting an answer to my question.

Turns out it was the pre-filter needing to be replaced - see page 14 - https://aquatruwater.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/AQT_Manual_UnderSinkMount_02.22_R8_WEB.pdf
I didn't think to do this because the system was working fine until I fixed the toilet supply - why would fixing the toilet suddenly make the pre-filter not work or to become clogged? Also, a customer service rep told me back when I bought it that 6 months is the minimum time, but that I could wait as long as 12 months.
Anyway, changing out that filter with a new one fixed the issue - the tank is filling now.

Turning the water off and on plus removing air, probably loosen some sediment in the pipes.  If you remove the faucet aerators, you might find some sediment on the screens also.

^^ that. Remove the faucet aerators temporarily. I bet you flush crud out of your pipes by removing them and running the water. One of the places I used to live in had this happen every time you turned off the water. If you removed the aerators and run the sinks the water would be brown for a minute.
